# C# .NET Class Library Initializing method (to load custom font)

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, class-library

I have a C# class library with .NET. It is a collection of win form UserControls to be imported into other projects. Some of the controls use a custom font, and so I want to use the code:

```
var pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
pfc.AddFontFile(@"C:\MyFont.ttf");
```

To load the custom font for use by all the controls. It makes sense to only do this once, so can I without loading it separately in the constructor for every userControl?
Is there some onInit DLL method? Can I make some static class in the DLL with a constructor that will be called the first time a userControl references it?

Comment: I think you are looking for the Singleton pattern?

Comment: The nofrmal technique is to not set the Font property of controls at all.  Not in the designer and not in code.  Which ensures that the controls' fonts are consistent throughout the UI, it borrows its Parent's font.  Which is what you are basically asking for